# Math percentage formula (a is bigger than b with 10%)

Tags: math, formula

How can I say in a math formula that:

a is bigger than b with 10% ?

I tried this:

a + 10%b > b
a > 10%b + b

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question. It's more suited to [math.se] instead.

Answer (score 0):

"*a is at least 10% bigger than b*" translates to "*a is greater than or equal to 1.10 times b.*"